# inherit part of base class

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have the following problem at hand. There is a class, `Foo` and another one called `Bar` which is a member of class `Foo`.

```
class Bar{
private:
    some stuff;
public:
    Bar();
    some other_stuff;
};
class Foo{
private:
    Bar bar;
public:
    Foo(); // Initialize the bar object here in the constructor
    void doSomethingWithBar();
};
```

Now both classes are huge! For some application, I need to make changes to both `Foo` and `Bar` and so there are `Foo_Derived` and `Bar_Derived` classes.

```
class Bar_Derived: public Bar{
private:
    some NEW_stuff;
public:
    Bar_Derived();
    some New_other_stuff;
};
class Foo_Derived: public Foo{
private:
    Bar_Derived bar;
public:
    Foo_Derived(); 
    void doSomethingWithBar();
};
```

As far as I understand inheritance, once `Foo_Derived()` is called, the base class constructor for Foo is also called which initializes the bar object in the base class (of type `Bar`. What should I do so that the bar object in the derived class is used instead? (of type `Bar_Derived`). I only need the base class (`Foo`) to initialize the base part of the bar object and do the rest in the `Foo_Derived` class myself. Is this even possible?

Sorry if the question is not clear. I'm just really confused myself!

Comment: It is not possible to inherit a part of a class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The base class initializer only does initialize the base part of the object, since that's all it knows about. A class initializer should only initialize those things that always need to be initialized for all members of that class.

In the constructor for `Foo_Derived`, you can use an initializer list to specify which `Bar_Derived` constructor to invoke. The `Bar_Derived` constructor can use any `Bar` constructor it wishes. If you don't have a `Bar_Derived` constructor that constructs `Foo_Derived::bar` the way you want it, you should write one or rethink how you have your hierarchy set up.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping I could avoid this. The simplest fix is to add the new stuff to the Bar_base but those wouldn't belong and is wrong since Foo knows nothing about the new stuff; only Foo_derived does. Another way I can think of fixing it, is have Foo and Bar be a member of Foo_derived and Bar_derived (which are no longer derived from Foo or Bar), this way I could make "wrappers" that directly call the appropriate functions in the base class when needed while adding some new stuff.